# How to generate links from artist profile page to genre/trait pages

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm attempting to make the genres and traits clickable links that forward to pages with lists of all artists related to given trait/genre.

This is my template for artist profile page

```
<h1>{{artist.stage_name}}</h1>
<h6>{{artist.real_name}}</h6>
<hr>
Genre:<a href="">{{artist.artist_genre}}</a>
<br>
Tratis:{{artist.artist_trait.all|join:", "}}
```

This is my current view. Do I have to query the genre's and traits separately?

```py
def ArtistProfileView(request, pk):
    artist = Artist.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'artist':artist, }
    return render(request, 'artist/artist_profile.html', context)
```

These are my models

```py
class ArtistGenre(models.Model):
    genre_name = models.CharField('Genre', max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('genre_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
  

class ArtistTrait(models.Model):
    trait_name = models.CharField('Trait', max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.trait_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('trait_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Artist(models.Model):
    stage_name = models.CharField('Stage Name', max_length=255)
    real_name = models.CharField('Birth Name', max_length=255, blank=True)
    artist_genre = models.ForeignKey(ArtistGenre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='artists')
    artist_trait = models.ManyToManyField(ArtistTrait, related_name='artists')
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.stage_name 
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_artist', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

These are my URLs

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ArtistIndex, name='index_artist'),
    path('artists/', views.ArtistListView.as_view(), name='artist_list'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.ArtistProfileView, name='profile_artist'),
    path('new/', views.ArtistCreateView.as_view(), name='new_artist'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.ArtistUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit_artist'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.ArtistDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_artist'),
    path('genres/', views.GenreListView.as_view(), name='genre_list'),
    path('genre/<int:pk>/', views.GenreProfileView, name='genre_profile'),
    path('traits/', views.TraitListView.as_view(), name='trait_list'),
    path('trait/<int:pk>/', views.TraitProfileView, name='trait_profile')
]
```

Thank You.

Comment: You don't have any url pattern named `genre_detail` did you mean `genre_profile`? Similarly for `trait_detail` did you mean `trait_profile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the template a little bit.

```
<h1>{{artist.stage_name}}</h1>
<h6>{{artist.real_name}}</h6>
<hr>


    
Genre:<a href="{{artist.artist_genre.get_absolute_url}}">{{artist.artist_genre}}</a>
<br>
Tratis:
{% for trait in artist.artist_trait.all%}
<a href="{{trait.get_absolute_url}}">{{trait.trait_name}}</a>, 
{% endfor %}
```

Also, there is an issue in your get_absolute_url method for both Genre and Trait. Instead of `genre_detail` and `trait_detail` it should be `genre_profile` and `trait_profile`. Alternatively, you can also change the `name` parameter of the URLs to `genre_detail` and `trait_detail` respectively.